# E-mail admin when customer changes address on frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, email, address

Is it possible to create an e-mail function to send the store administrator an e-mail when a customer changes his/her address on the My Account page?

How can i accomplish this, where and how should i start?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible using an observer.

1. Hook onto an event fired before changes are made but POST data is available, so you can compare "before" and "after". `controller_action_predispatch_customer_address_formPost` looks like a good candidate.
2. Compare already saved data and data being saved. How a "change" is determined is up to you.
3. Send an email if changes are detected. [[How to send email]](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/sending-emails-programmatically-in-magento)

Done.